# preg_match_all function to clip integers

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
    <div class="final-pro" itemprop="pro"> 
    <meta itemprop="curr" content="yen">
    <span style="font-family: yen">d </span>15,675
    <span class="base-pro linethrough">
    <span style="font-family: yen">d </span>14,999
    </span>
    </div>
```

I need to clip the Values 15,675 and 14,999 from the above html codes using preg_match_all. i tried as much as possible but failed.Helping hands are welcome.

What I've tried so far:

```
preg_match_all('/yen">d </span>(.*?)<\span/s',$con,$val);
```

Comment: post the pattern that you tried?

Comment: $value=preg_match_all('/yen">d </span>(.*?)<\span/s',$con,$val);

Comment: @StoppieChandruDiGi you don't need such pattern check my answer. Btw `/` needs to be escaped.

Comment: thank you @Robert but these code are from large HTML document how can I suppose to do clip integers from particular div class like <div class="final-pro"> </div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$txt = '<div class="final-pro" itemprop="pro"> 
<meta itemprop="curr" content="yen">
<span style="font-family: yen">d </span>15,675
<span class="base-pro linethrough">
<span style="font-family: yen">d </span>14,999
</span>
</div>';


$matches = array();

preg_match_all('/[0-9,]+/', $txt, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

It is just about `[0-9,]+` which looks for numbers and `,` that's all.

**Output**

```
Array ( [0] => 
              Array ( 
                      [0] => 15,675 
                      [1] => 14,999 
                    ) 
      )
```

if you need more complicated Regex to fit your needs you can use

```
preg_match_all('/font-family: yen">d <\/span>([0-9,]+)/', $txt, $matches);
```

Edit:

If you want to find these numbers in whole div then the regex needs to be more complicated

```
preg_match('/<div class\="final\-pro" itemprop="pro">.*?<\/span>([0-9,]+).*?<\/span>([0-9,]+).*?<\/div>/s', $txt, $matches);
```

Take a look at `/s` modifier that enables "single-line mode". In this mode, the dot matches newlines.

Comment: no improvements sir. i'm getting result "d and d as the result"

Comment: I'm not sir ;P if this satisfy you please use "mark" to make it as answer and close question.